# HTACCESS Dynamic Variable within an IfModule tag

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-pagespeed

**How To Get a Variable Inside IfModule?**

I want Apache to replace *%{HTTP_HOST}*....  can that be done within an IfModule tag?

I am trying to setup Mod_Pagespeed in my .htaccess to work across multiple domains.  This .htaccess file will be running on, dev, staging and production servers...  each with a different cname (sub domain).  We are on apache 2.2, so we cannot run an IfElse statement.

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed on

  ModPagespeedDomain *.example.com
  ModPagespeedDomain localhost

  ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_domains
  ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain %{HTTP_HOST} images.example.com

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Apache does not evaluate `%{...}` variables. Instead each individual module has to evaluate them. `mod_pagespeed` does not currently evaluate them.

You could request it as a feature at: https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list . I think I remember there being a similar feature request, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know exactly how modules handle this kind of information.  I never came up with a solution, we had to manually go into each box dev, staging and production and set that ModPagespeedDomain with the proper value.